# CSS Local Font not showing up

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am at that point where I don't know anymore what I should have coded wrong. For test purposes I want to use a local font for my website. But I don't get it to be displayed on all devices. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
 <head>
    some basic stuff ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;

    font-family: 'Circular Std Book', Helvetica, Arial, " sans-serif"!important;
    src: url('CircularStd-Book.eot');
    src: url('CircularStd-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('CircularStd-Book.woff') format('woff'),
        url('CircularStd-Book.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('CircularStd-Book.svg#CircularStd-Book') format('svg'); 
    }
```

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xIks.jpg)

It does work on my desktop computer, but not on any other pc...
Thanks for your help.

Still not working with this one:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Circular Std Book', Helvetica, Arial, " sans-serif"!important;
    src: url('../font/CircularStd-Book.eot');
    src: url('../font/CircularStd-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/CircularStd-Book.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/CircularStd-Book.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/CircularStd-Book.svg#CircularStd-Book') format('svg');    
}

body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-family: 'Circular Std Book', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: Are the fonts stored in the same directory as style.css?

Comment: No, the fonts are in the folder /font and the style in the folder /css/style.css

Comment: Do you have that font installed on your working desktop? That might explain why it would work locally but not elsewhere, and would also mean there is still a problem with the CSS or fonts.

Comment: That's true, i have installed it locally. But what is wrong with your code? Everything seems so right to me...

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to be missing `@font-face`

See an example of it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

body {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
}
```

Also as mentioned, check the path is correct. The path is relative to the CSS file itself.

Comment: Ah, I missed the @font-face.

Comment: I didn't know it's relative to the CSS but it makes sense. Thank's for that. Anyways it's still not displaying...

Comment: You also don't need to quote `sans-serif`

Comment: @Julian Do you see any 404s in the console?

Comment: No 404s @AndFisher

Comment: The font is showing up on my desctop computer like before, but not on any other device. Don't get it.

Comment: @Julian can you update your question to list the devices that are causing you a problem?

Comment: Am I the only who when I use `@font-face` the ENTIRE css stops working? no bolding, no colors, etc. Just keeps using Times New Roman. Doesn't even work with local fonts in iOS or custom.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a fallback option in the font-family with the !important tag caused this error. I've removed the fallback and here's the final working code:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'CircularStdBook';
    src: url('CircularStd-Book.eot');
    src: url('../font/CircularStd-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/CircularStd-Book.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/CircularStd-Book.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/CircularStd-Book.svg#CircularStd-Book') format('svg');    
}

body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-family: 'CircularStdBook', Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Thank's for your help.