# CSS Fonts Not Working

Tags: html, css, fonts

So i'm trying to import a custom font located in `/fonts/FONT.woff2` but when i add a new font family for it etc it just reverts the font to what i'm guessing is default ( Looks like Arial )

```
@font-face {
  font-family: AvonValleyFont;
  src: url(../fonts/FONT.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: AvonValleyFont;
  color:#4e4e4e;
  line-height: 22px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'AvonValleyFont', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: make sure your font file path are correct

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015441/css-local-font-not-showing-up/41015669#41015669

Comment: @SuperUser that answer is not even helpful.. why use that as a reference to close this question